# D3.js - Retrieving DOM subset given data subset

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3.js to create a large number of svg:ellipse elements (~5000).  After the initial rendering some of the data items can be updated via the backend (I'll know which ones) and I want to change the color of those ellipses (for example).

Is there a fast way to recover the DOM element or elements associated with a data item or items?  Other than the obvious technique if recomputing a join over the full set of DOM elements with the subset of data?

```
var myData = [{ id: 'item1'}, { id: 'item2' }, ... { id: 'item5000' }];
var create = d3.selectAll('ellipse).data(myData, function(d) { return d.id; });
create.enter().append('ellipse').each(function(d) {
    // initialize ellipse
});

// later on

// this works, but it seems like it would have to iterate over all 5000 elements
var subset = myData.slice(1200, 1210); // just an example
var updateElements = d3.selectAll('ellipse').data(subset, function(d) { return d.id; });
updateElements.each(function(d) {
    // this was O(5000) to do the join, I _think_
    // change color or otherwise update
});
```

I'm rendering updates multiple times per second (as fast as possible, really) and it seems like O(5000) to update a handful of elements is a lot.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
create.enter().append('ellipse').each(function(d) {
    d.__dom = this;
    // continue with initialization
});

// later on

// pull the dom nodes back out
var subset = myData.slice(1200, 1210).map(function(d) { return d.__dom; });
d3.selectAll(subset).each(function(d) {
    // now it should be O(subset.length)
});
```

This works.  But it seems like this would be a common pattern, so I'm wondering if there is a standard way to solve this problem?  I actually want to use my data in multiple renderings, so I would need to be more clever so they don't trip over each other.

Basically, I know that d3 provides a map from DOM -> data via domElement.`__data__`.  Is there a fast and easy way to compute the reverse map, other than caching the values myself manually?

I need to get from data -> DOM.

Comment: This is not a general way to solve it, but in your case if you know already which elements will change and which will not, you can put them in `g.will-change` and `g.will-not-change`. Then selecting them would be easy and cheap. However, if the subset which changes is different each time, one could choose from several different approaches I can explain in an answer.

Comment: Different pieces of data are changing continuously.  Tagging the DOM won't solve my problem.  I need to actually be able to update the DOM with just a reference to the data item.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you keep the d3 selection reference alive (`create` in your example), D3 is using a map to map the data keys to DOM nodes in the update so it's actually O(log n).

We can do some testing with the D3 update /data operator method vs a loop method over the subset:

```
var d3UpdateMethod = function() {
    svg.selectAll("ellipse").data(subset, keyFunc)
        .attr("style", "fill:green");
}
var loopMethod = function() {
    for (var i=0; i < subset.length; i++) {
        svg.selectAll(".di" + i)
        .attr("style", "fill:green");
    }
}
var timedTest = function(f) {
    var sumTime=0;
    for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        var startTime = Date.now();
        f();
        sumTime += (Date.now() - startTime);
    }
    return sumTime / 10;
};
var nextY = 100;
var log = function(text) {
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", width/2)
        .attr("y", nextY+=100)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("style", "fill:red")
        .text(text);
};

log("d3UpdateMethod time:" + timedTest(d3UpdateMethod));
log("loopMethod time:" + timedTest(loopMethod));
```

I also created a fiddle to demonstrate what I understand you're trying to do [here](http://jsfiddle.net/activescott/dapPG/).

---

Another method to make it easy to track the nodes that are in your subset is by adding a CSS class to the subset. For example:

```
var ellipse = svg.selectAll("ellipse").data(data, keyFunc).enter()
    .append("ellipse")
    .attr("class", function (d) { 
        var cl = "di" + d.i;
        if (d.i % 10 == 0)
            cl+= " subset"; //<< add css class for those nodes to be updated later
        return cl;
    })
    ...
```

Note how the "subset" class would be added only to those nodes that you know are in your subset to be updated later. You can then select them later for an update with the following:

```
svg.selectAll("ellipse.subset").attr("style", "fill:yellow");
```

I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/activescott/dapPG/) to include this test too and it's nearly as fast as the directMethod.

Comment: The fiddle is a good start, but not quite.  I updated the fiddle to more accurately reflect the trade-off I'm considering.  I see your point about evaluating how d3 performs internally, but as you can see the direct caching of the DOM nodes for selection is about 20 times faster than the join subset method. http://jsfiddle.net/dapPG/9/

Comment: Cool use of each there. If you can always cache the values yourself manually and perf is the most important thing for you, that is the fastest since there is no more lookup from Data -> DOM (as you have the list of DOM elements directly). I guess just misunderstood your question, as I thought you were asking for another way to map from Data > DOM using D3-ish way/pattern.

Comment: well, yeah, I am fishing for another way.  I know how to solve my problem, but I'll find myself writing similar code and doing book-keeping in lot's of places my way.  My question is does d3 have a standard way to achieve what I'm looking for other than me doing manual book-keeping - though on further thought I'm guessing the answer is "no" for the same reason I dont' want to do it.  d3 doesn't know how many places I'll use the data, so it might have to track multiple dom nodes and distinguish between which one I want in each case, which it can't do but I can(though painfully).

Comment: @MikeEdwards at the risk of belaboring the point :) D3 _does_ have a way to do what you asked (a map from DOM -> data) and that is what I explained. Of course though, naturally a map/lookup is not as fast as going through a list of already looked up items. I also added another approach to my answer by tagging the "to update" nodes with a css class and that you can use as a selector later. This is _almost_ as fast as the direct method. Hope this helps.